# [19141:19141:0425/011526.129520:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374) InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chrome-extension

When I run the `google-chrome`

**- [19141:19141:0425/011526.129520:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)]
   InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process
   gpu-process.**

This error is coming also chrome is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with Vivaldi and could launch it using this command:

```bsh
$ vivaldi-stable  %U --password-store=basic
```

Maybe this can launch `google-chrome` too. I am not sure what the original problem has been in my case and how this fixes it.

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrTzc-E8oTc).

**UPDATE 1:**

Well I have some more info on possible cause of my issue. I noticed that `Evolution` was not also running properly. It was not able to sync the imap folders. I use fingerprint login in Ubuntu 20.04 and after logging in, it always used to ask for my actual password when launching `Vivaldi`.

This time, I noticed that after logging in with fingerprint it did not ask for a password when trying to launch `Vivaldi` and as mentioned above, `Vivaldi` didn't launch either.

So I logged out and logged back in my password. This time, both `Vivaldi` and `Evolution` worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

"[Solving Google Chrome's gpu-process error message in Ubuntu Linux](https://simpleit.rocks/linux/ubuntu/fixing-common-google-chrome-gpu-process-error-message-in-linux/)" worked for me.

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

It disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch.

Comment: the command line isn't in use when we use that command

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete configurations:

```
rm -rdf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Also maybe you need to delete the cache:

```
rm -rdf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

**Please note that this will reset your google chrome completely. Just like you installed it fresh.**